# Parameter value not passed in ASP.NET MVC route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, parameters, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm learning about creating custom routes in ASP.NET MVC and have hit a brick wall. In my Global.asax.cs file, I've added the following:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );

    // My Custom Route.
    routes.MapRoute(
        "User_Filter",
        "home/filter/{name}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Filter", name = String.Empty }
    );
}
```

The idea is for me to able to navigate to `http://localhost:123/home/filter/mynameparam`. Here is my controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Filter(string name)
    {
        return this.Content(String.Format("You found me {0}", name));
    }
}
```

When I navigate to `http://localhost:123/home/filter/mynameparam` the contoller method `Filter` is called, but the parameter `name` is always `null`.

Could someone give a pointer as to the correct way for me to build my custom route, so that it passes the name part in the url into the `name` parameter for `Filter()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Default` route should be the last one.
Try it this way:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    // My Custom Route.
    routes.MapRoute(
        "User_Filter",
        "home/filter/{name}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Filter", name = String.Empty }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
}
```

Comment: Great stuff, that did the trick. Will need to keep in mind about route ordering from now on. Cheers for all the answers to this question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your routes need to be the other way round?

The routes are processed in order, so if the first (default, OOTB) route matches the URL, that's the one that'll be used.